Carpi's sufficient condition for the abelian nth power freeness of a morphism in 1993
I'm working on Carpi's article on Abelian k-power free mentioned below:
"ARTURO CARPI, ON ABELIAN POWER-FREE MORPHISMS, International Journal of Algebra and Computation Vol. 03, No. 02, pp. 151-167 (1993)".
He gives a sufficient condition for the abelian nth power freeness of a morphism

I don't understand exactly what (iii) condition means:
Why do $i$ values ​​range from $0$ to $n$? It doesn't have to be $n$ letters or
$h(a_i)$ may not have $n$ prefixes. I couldn't understand what the indices meant.
Can you please explain what condition (iii) says? And I would appreciate it if you could explain it with an example.

Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post. Here is why.
